# issues with onClick event not getting triggered on DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I've got an API that returns me `{"html", "Css" and "JS"}` that i'd ideally like to render on client side.

**Issue:**
Looks like something's failing for some reason and clicking on the button does not do anything. (I have accept button)

**JavaScript:**

```
function postAjax(success) {
    var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr.open('GET', '/myaccount/profile/api/accept');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState > 3 && xhr.status == 200) {
            success();
        }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json', 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(null);
    return xhr;
};
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
        // some logic
        var cookieLanguage = document.getElementById("CookieContent_wrapper");
        var cookieBanner = document.getElementById("CookieBanner");
        var acceptAllButton = document.getElementById("acceptAllButton");
        acceptAllButton.onclick = function() {  // Does not get trigerred.
            // Does not get trigerred.
            // Do some logic.
        };
    }
};
```

However, acceptAllButton.onClick event is not triggerred.

This is my directive.js (angular)

```
    populate() {

        this.cookieBannerData = this.models.CookieData; // We are getting { "js", "html", "css"}

        //CSS
        $("head").prepend( this.cookieBannerData.css );

        // HTML
        let div = document.getElementById( 'cookie-banner-outerwrap' );
        div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', this.cookieBannerData.html );


        //JS
        $("head").append( this.cookieBannerData.js );
    }


    template.html

    <div id="cookie-banner-outerwrap"></div>
```

When I click on the button, nothing happens. Is there anyway I can bind the onclick event with window so that I can get my

Comment: Is this AngularJS (aka Angular v1.x) or Angular (aka Angular v2.x+)?

Comment: angular 1.x @DanielWStrimpel

Comment: Do you define the handler before or after the dom is rendered/appended/ready?

Comment: In the code, it's after `if (document.readyState == "interactive") {` I call `acceptAllButton.onclick`

Comment: I *strongly* recommend that you don't mix jQuery and Angular. They are both DOM manipulation frameworks and do not play well together. Instead you should be using the `ng-click` directive on your button to call a method on your controller.

Comment: @Lex unfortunately I don't have that choice since this is coming from a third party API that supports many services.